# Is it possible to export based on query in relational tables?

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, export

I  have 2 tables. These tables are relational tables.
Table-A = wp_posts 
Table-B = wp_postmeta 
Please look at the example table image:[image: Here]

I want to perform a query in table B according to the "id" of the rows whose post type value is product or product_variation in Table A.

After querying, I will export the table. However, I couldn't do that. The query I wrote gives an error or I cannot export it. I cannot export it because, i get a warning like "*MySQL: Current selection does not contain a unique column...[(Like this)](https://i.ibb.co/8ztdLsX/zxcasdsad.png)*".

I want to export the data obtained as a result of the query as SQL language with the phpmyadmin export tool.  I will then use this data on another server. 
I've been dealing with this for a few hours. I'd be happy to show you the way.

My query:
I can't export it. 
MySQL: Current selection does not contain a unique column...:

```
SELECT
  pm.*
FROM wp_posts AS ps
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
    ON ps.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE ps.post_type = 'product' OR ps.post_type = 'product_variation'
```

Comment: export or import? You have a query you say works, but you don't show what you do to export (or import? to where?) the result. Please edit your question (and probably tags also) to show the whole process, preferably with no images for data.

Comment: I edited. I hope it was more descriptive. Thank you.

Comment: I would next try `CREATE TABLE... SELECT` syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html to formally create a table rather than just a result set. You can then define a primary key based on the two columns and that would probably make the exporter happy.

Comment: Also you can consider using `SELECT... INTO OUTFILE` and using `LOAD DATA` on the other machine(s).